# Ajax not working in url with parameters

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a problem with ajax. The code works correctly on this url http://www.web.com/index.php?s=formulario but not in this http://www.web.com/index.php?s=formulario&var=1050

In the urls with parameters ajax returns no results but other works perfect. 
I can't find the problem. Any help?

Mi code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var consulta;

      $("#dni").focus();

      $("#dni").keyup(function(e){
             consulta = $("#dni").val();

             $("#resultado_dni").delay(1000).queue(function(n) {      

                  $("#resultado_dni").html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');

                        $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              url: "comprobar_dni.php",
                              data: "b="+consulta,
                              dataType: "html",
                              error: function(){
                                    alert("error petición ajax");
                              },
                              success: function(data){                                                      
                                    $("#resultado_dni").html(data);                                      
                                    $("#valid_dni").val(data);
                                    n();
                              }
                  });

             });

      });

});
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: In the console I see this error (only in the url with parameters) http://www.legionvps.com/error1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try to change 'dataType' to:

```
dataType: "json",
```

After ajax is complete, callback data should be parsed by type.

Comment: I tried changing this but still not working =(.
The console still shows this error (only in the url with parameters): http://www.legionvps.com/error1.jpg

Comment: Looks like 'data' is broken.
Mb, response format is not html/json.
Can you copy your's code to jsfiddle?

Comment: I have php code and doesn't show well in jsfiddle but here: http://jsfiddle.net/d1vpcLmm/

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Did you try to send ajax without 'dataType'?
Try make console.log(data), without 'dataType' in params.
I think that response couldn't be parsed.
Also try to change type of ajax.